# Why is glob ignoring some directories?

Tags: python, windows, escaping, glob, backslash

I'm trying to find all `*.txt` files in a directory with `glob()`. In some cases, `glob.glob('some\path\*.txt')` gives an empty string, despite existing files in the given directories. This is especially true, if `path` is all lower-case or numeric. 
As a minimal example I have two folders `a` and `A` on my `C:` drive both holding one `Test.txt` file.

```
import glob
files1 = glob.glob('C:\a\*.txt')
files2 = glob.glob('C:\A\*.txt')
```

yields

```
files1 = []
files2 = ['C:\\A\\Test.txt']
```

If this is by design, is there any other directory name, that leads to such unexpected behaviour?

(I'm working on win 7, with Python 2.7.10 (32bit))

**EDIT:** (2019) Added an answer for Python 3 using `pathlib`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `\a` has a special meaning in string literals (bell char).

Just double backslashes when inserting paths in string literals (i.e. use `"C:\\a\\*.txt"`).

[Python is different from C](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) because when you use backslash with a character that doesn't have a special meaning (e.g. `"\s"`) Python keeps both the backslash and the letter (in C instead you would get just the `"s"`).

This sometimes hides the issue because things just work anyway even with a single backslash (depending on what is the first letter of the directory name) ...

Comment: So, to be safe, I double every backslash! Great, solved it. Is there a list of special characters?

Comment: When using string pathnames under Windows, it is best to use [raw string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) and not remember which escapes are needed. For example, using `r'c:\a\*.txt'` is stored as `'c:\\a\\*.txt'`. You might even find it useful to use forward slashes `'c:/a/*.txt'`; I think that Windows accepts forward slashes except in CMD.EXE

Comment: @Dschoni: I've added a link to Python documentation page about string literals. That page includes a table of all recognized escape sequences.

Comment: @msw, except a raw string literal can't end on a backslash, so it doesn't work for the root directory, e.g. `'C:\\'`. Generally the Win32 API will translate forward slashes to backslashes. However, the NT kernel's object namespace only recognizes backslash as a path separator, so you have to use backslashes when using the ``\\?\`` prefix. (This prefix bypasses Win32 path processing to allow using fully-qualified NT paths that can have up to 32768 characters.)

Answer (score 2):

I personally avoid using double-backslashes in Windows and just use Python's handy raw-string format. Just change your code to the following and you won't have to escape the backslashes:

```
import glob
files1 = glob.glob(r'C:\a\*.txt')
files2 = glob.glob(r'C:\A\*.txt')
```

Notice the `r` at the beginning of the string.

As already mentioned, the `\a` is a special character in Python. Here's a link to a list of Python's string literals:

- https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Answer (score 0):

As my original answer attracted more views than expected and some time has passed. I wanted to add an answer that reliably solves this kind of problems and is also cross-plattform compatible. It's in python 3 on Windows 10, but should also work on *nix systems.

```
from pathlib import Path
filepath = Path(r'C:\a')
filelist = list(filepath.glob('*.txt'))

--> [WindowsPath('C:/a/Test.txt')]
```

I like this solution better, as I can copy and paste paths directly from windows explorer, without the need to add or double backslashes etc.